# Netbeans 7 auto-completion for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans7.0

I am Working on NetBeans 7.0. JavaScript auto completion is working on some cases but not on all. I think very simple cases are working
Let say i have a global object/var

```
var str = "abcdef";

str. // auto completion popup window triggered for this.

function f(){ 

  str. // no auto completion popup window triggered for this.

}
```

i don't know how complete is the support for auto completion for JS in NetBeans, but this is kind of annoying. Anybody else facing similar issue?

Comment: It's alwarys like that.. The autocomplete is not that good for js in netbeans. The good thing is, if you explicitly trigger the instant help again. It will pop up more methods for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How to you explicit trigger instant help? do you know any editor which have better support of JS than NetBeans

Comment: for eg. if i am trying to use str. it never show indexOf() as a method although it list other methods for the string object.

Comment: For instance, I have configured my key combination 'ctrl + \' to trigger the instant help. If I have a var called 'str', I type in str.in and press ctrl+\, it will auto complete as something like str.indexOf(arg1, arg2 ..)

Comment: Got it it works:) thanks. Do you know any editor which is better than NetBeans for JavaScript. Thanks for the help.

Comment: jetBrains IDE's are quite good. I, after using NetBeans for 4 years, never returned to NB after trying out one of JetBrains IDE's. _Disclaimer: I'm not, in any way, associated with JB; just a happy user :)_